# Tips on Application logging

Tags: .net, logging

I was going over some tips from javacodegeeks. Was wondering if this article summarizes all the tips and best practices.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html

Are there anymore that I should be thinking of

Answer (score 1):

I'd add one more: logging is the "hello world" of aspect oriented programming.  If you aren't using aspects, you're writing too much code.

Comment: @CodeToGlory - look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653013/is-there-an-aspect-already-written-and-tested-well-for-trace-logging

Comment: @CodeToGlory - take a look at these 2 questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313789/what-is-aspectj-good-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708776/what-is-the-most-common-use-for-aop-in-spring-project

Comment: I would love for some .Net examples.

Comment: Don't you have Google installed?  Isn't the term enough of a lead?   http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+aspect+oriented+programming

Answer (score 0):

I liked the referenced article very much. The only thing i miss is: **Define a logging strategy before you start developping an applicaton**

Usually logging means writing messages a la "now im doing this" or "Caught Exception Xy".

With "logging strategy" i mean decide who will see what type of message under which circumstances. In my applications if usually have

- technical message for developper/admins. purpose: to document and fix problems.
- messages that might be displayed to endusers (i.e. in the statusbar or parts of an errormessage). These should be understandable by endusers
- a definition which logginglevel (verbose, debug, info, warn, error, fatal) is used when.